# javaScript code is not working

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = 0.025399;

function calculatebmi() {
    var weight = +document.bmiform1.weight.value;
    var feet = +document.bmiform.feet.value;
    var inches = +document.bmiform.inches.value;
    inches = 12 * feet + inches;
    var height = x * inches;
    var finalbmi = weight / (height * height);
    document.bmiform3.bmi.value = finalbmi;
}

function validate() {
    var age = document.ageForm.age.value;
    var feet = document.bmiform.feet.value;
    var inches = document.bmiform.inches.value;
    var weight = document.bmiform1.weight.value;

    if (age == "" || feet == "" || inches == "" || weight == "") {
        alert("Your fields are empty");
    }
}
</script>
```

And My html is

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <h4>Enter Your Age</h4></td>
    <td>
        <form name="ageForm">
            <input type="text" name="age" size="5px" />AGE
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <h4>Enter your height</h4></td>
    <td>
        <form name="bmiform">
            <input type="text" name="feet" size="5px" /> FEET
            <input type="text" name="inches" size="5px" /> inches
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <h4>Enter your weight</h4></td>
    <td>
        <form name="bmiform1">
            <input type="text" name="weight" size="5px" /> KG
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <form name="bmiform3">
            Your BMI:
            <input type="text" name="bmi" />
            <input class="button1" type="button" name="calculate" value="Calculate" title="calculate" onclick="calculatebmi()" />

        </form>
    </td>
```

When i donot fill the age,weight,height field it didn't propmt any alert box as i told it to do using script? Can anybody help me to find out what is going wrong here any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Where are you calling the functions?

Comment: You're not calling `validate()`

Comment: can i call both functions on click on same button...if yes how can i do it

Comment: `onclick="validate();calculatebmi()"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following changes in your code to make it work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x=0.025399;
    function calculatebmi()
    {
      if(validate()){ //will continue only if validate function returns true
      var weight=+document.bmiform1.weight.value;
      var feet=+document.bmiform.feet.value;
      var inches=+document.bmiform.inches.value;
      inches=12*feet+inches;
      var height=x*inches;
      var finalbmi=weight/(height*height);
      document.bmiform3.bmi.value=finalbmi;     
       }
    }

    function validate()
    {
        var age    = document.ageForm.age.value;
        var feet   = document.bmiform.feet.value;
        var inches = document.bmiform.inches.value;
        var weight = document.bmiform1.weight.value;

        if(age =="" || feet=="" || inches=="" || weight=="")
        {
            alert("Your fields are empty");
            return false;
        }
        return true; //returning true

    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call validate function in calculatebmi before doing any processing.

```
    function calculatebmi()
    {
       validate();
        var weight=+document.bmiform1.weight.value;
      var feet=+document.bmiform.feet.value;
        var inches=+document.bmiform.inches.value;
        inches=12*feet+inches;
        var height=x*inches;
        var finalbmi=weight/(height*height);
        document.bmiform3.bmi.value=finalbmi;     
   }
```